# event based openssl bio

Tags: c, openssl

I found example code at https://gist.github.com/darrenjs/4645f115d10aa4b5cebf57483ec82eca that uses openssl BIO to implement "nonblocking" socket IO.

But in main function `poll` only listens stdin and socket fd. poll never listens rbio and wbio.

Is it means function `BIO_write` and `BIO_read` are blocking? If they are blocking it makes that code blocking right? If they are not blocking why `poll` function doesn't listen that `BIO`s?

I tried to use `BIO_get_fd` function but it always returns 0. I think it not supposed to create fd as default. I tried to init BIO with `*bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_fd())` but still `BIO_get_fd` returns 0.

I created two pipe `int pipes[2][2]` used function `BIO_set_fd` and gave pipes[0][1] to rbio and gave pipes[1][1] to wbio. `BIO_write` works with that way. But `SSL_read` function fails with error `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` I think it means `SSL_read` tried to read pipes[0][1]. I know pipes as one way use like; pipe[0] will be used for read pipe[1] will use for write. But I didn't find way to set pipe[0] pipe[1] to same BIO.

Is it possible to implement pipes to openssl BIOs?

If it's not possible how i can say openssl to create their BIO fd so I can use that fd in poll/epoll/etc?

Note; my main target is doing event based BIO without using socket fd in SSL/BIO functions. I'll handle data transfer between socket fd and BIO fd.

Answer (score 2):

`poll` only needs to listen to `stdin` and `socket.fd`, because that is where `rbio` gets its data from and where `wbio` writes to.

`BIO_write` and `BIO_read` are as blocking as their underlying medium. In case of network they can be considered blocking. But in case of your example they are both `BIO_s_mem`, pure memory-base BIO-s. As such you can consider them non-blocking.

Skipping ahead, **it is** possible to create BIO on pretty much anything. If you have a file descriptor (FD) then you don't have to do anything, just use `BIO_s_fd`. If for some reason you don't like it you can always implement your own BIO. It's not too hard and there are several examples out there.